# Validation rule for outlook

Tags: validation-rule

When is validation rules applied when using Salesforce for Outlook? Is it everytime data is saved or every time data is synced with outlook?

Comment: Synchronize with Salesforce—During synchronizations, records modified in Outlook will be reflected in Salesforce, and vice versa.

Comment: For my case I have a validation rule on Event that prevent a user to select an account as the related to, but this is not firing from SFO. Any user using SFO is able to relate an account to an event. Even trigger is not detecting this. Why does salesforce breaking all the rules? Has someone came across this ??

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above answer as I have been researching this mystery as well.  It seems that validation rules in GENERAL are applied every time a record is saved...but with Salesforce for Outlook the research is showing that it happens when data is synched with the server.